Command \glossariescaptionsportuges already defined when both Portuguese and Brazilian are enabled
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[portuguese,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
Text
\end{document}

It would result in:
Command \glossariescaptionsportuges already defined.

I understand that enabling both Portuguese and Brazilian in a same document seems strange, but it is for the usage inside a document class to allow users selecting which language variant is to be used. Is there thus some way to fix this issue?

I think it’s a bug in glossaries. The error is not raised with the following hack (before loading this package): \AddToHook{file/glossaries-portuges.ldf/before}{\let\glossariescaptionsportuges\relax}. But I don’t know if the captions are right.
